# I am trying to make a login form with fetching records from database

Tags: java

I am trying to make a login form with fetching records from database, it runs successfully when the record is on first position but when it is on 2nd position it first gives Record not found output, then Record found.

Here is my instance code.

```
for(int i=1;i<noOfColumn;i++)
{        
    while(rs.next())
    {
        if(x.equals(rs.getString(1)))
        {
            if(kk.equals(rs.getString(2)))
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(l1, "Logged in successfully");
                break;
            }
        }
        else
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(b1, "Log in Failed");
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the outer `for-loop` for?

Comment: Please post your query which you have used to login

Answer (score 3):

You don't need a for loop and the below code can work but this is not efficient so please post us the query what you have used,

Use the query like **select * from table_name where username=x and password=kk**.
If you have any record with a valid username and password then your while loop will be executed.

```
PreparedStatement statement = sqlConnection.prepareStatement("SELECT userId, password FROM login where username=? and password=?");
statement.setString(1, unametype);
statement.setString(2, passwordtype);
ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery();
// It is better to use prepared statement rather than executing sql strings directly. Because if you use sql string you might face sql injection attacks


boolean flag=false;

while(rs.next())
{
    flag=true;       
}

if(flag)
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(l1, "Logged in successfully");
else
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(b1, "Log in Failed");
```

Comment: +1 because fetching everything is (imho) senseless. Fetching what you need and look if query is successfull is the result and should be much much faster.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that there is a need for you to have a for loop
you just have to get the resultset by executing your sql statement and iterate through it like

```
PreparedStatement statement = sqlConnection.prepareStatement("SELECT userId, password FROM login where username=? and password=?");
statement.setString(1, unametype);
statement.setString(2, passwordtype);
ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery();
while(rs.next()){
    if(rs.getString(1).equals(usernametype)){
       if(rs.getString(2).equals(passwordtype)){
          // successful message
       }else{
          // invalid password
       }
    }else{
       // invalid username
    }   
}
```